How to throttle network for a single docker container
For a crowdsourcing application I need a server that can do the following:
Host a WebRTC call between 2 clients
Simulate various network conditions (low bandwith, delay, etc.) and switch between them
Handle multiple of these video calls with manipulated network at the same time, each with different network manipulations
I have succesfully used the the official Coturn Docker image to spin up a single TURN server and make a video call over it.
How can I now introduce network artifacts into this setup? Ultimately I will probably need an own TURN server for every single ongoing call, so that I can manipulate the network strength individually.
Steps Taken

I tried using tc inside the container, but the Coturn Docker Image doesn't have that (or any other shell utility) installed.
This answer seems like a way to do it from outside the container, but I get the same errors as described in the comments and no solution is provided.


You may try the pumba netem command from the Pumba tool.

Pumba is a chaos testing command line tool for Docker containers. Pumba disturbs your containers by crashing containerized application, emulating network failures and stress-testing container resources (cpu, memory, fs, io, and others).

Here is the CLI documentation for the netem command:
pumba netem -h

NAME:
   Pumba netem - delay, loss, duplicate and re-order (run 'netem') packets, to emulate different network problems

USAGE:
   Pumba netem command [command options] [arguments...]

COMMANDS:
     delay      delay egress traffic
     loss
     duplicate
     corrupt
     rate       limit egress traffic

OPTIONS:
   --duration value, -d value   network emulation duration; should be smaller than recurrent interval; use with optional unit suffix: 'ms/s/m/h'
   --interface value, -i value  network interface to apply delay on (default: "eth0")
   --target value, -t value     target IP filter; comma separated. netem will impact only on traffic to target IP(s)
   --tc-image value             Docker image with tc (iproute2 package); try 'gaiadocker/iproute2'
   --help, -h                   show help

In particular, you can have a look at the examples for netem delay, netem loss, netem corrupt and netem rate sub-commands.
